# Como puedo convertir mi data JSON en una clase?

Tags: c#, json, set

estoy tratando de pasar este JSON y convertirlo a mi clase X para poder en este caso mostrar la info y posterior editar

Esta es mi respuesta JSON:

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://office.cl:50346/b1s/v1/",
    "value": 
    [
        {
            "CardCode": "123FM",
            "CardName": "FARMATODO",
            "FederalTaxID": "1,822,005-9",
            "CurrentAccountBalance": 0.0
        }
    ],
    "odata.nextLink": "/b1s/v1/?$select=CardCode,CardName,CurrentAccountBalance,FederalTaxID&$skip=20"
}
```

entonces necesito setear esta info en mi clase , ya lo hize con una lista pero no logro hacerlo con un obj unico.

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

foreach (var s in obj)
{
    tempPartner = s["CardCode"];
    tempPartner = s.CardCode;
    Console.WriteLine(s.CardCode);
}

return tempPartner;
```

También usé `JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);` , pero sin resultados exitosos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No estás consiguiendo lo que buscas porque tus datos están dentro de `"value"` y dentro de `"value"` están en una lista, por lo que puedes exportarlo directamente en una Lista.

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
List<Class1> lst = obj.value.ToObject(typeof(List<Class1>));
```

Date cuenta de que en el JSON que nos pasas `obj` tiene las propiedades `{odata.metadata, value, odata.nextLink}` y tus datos se encuentran en `"value"`

Lo que hago en este código es hacer un `deserialize` del objeto que recibes y lo convierto en un `dynamic obj`, ese objeto tiene las 3 propiedades mencionadas, entonces como solo queremos obtener los datos de `value` (que es una lista) le hacemos un casteo en una lista de un objetos con las propiedades que te trae:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string CardCode;
    public string CardName;
    public string FederalTaxID;
    public int CurrentAccountBalance;
}
```

Haciendo esto podrias ir a leer las propiedades facilmente usando el objeto creado con un simple `lst[0].CardCode` (por ejemplo).

Te dejo el [enlace de las pruebas que he hecho](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T3JjiP) para que puedas hacer las pruebas.